# ruby, `match': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I have some problem with UTF-8 conding. I have read some posts here but still it does not work properly somehow.

That is my code:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
#encoding: utf-8

def determine
  file=File.open("/home/lala.txt")          
  file.each do |line|           
    puts(line)
    type = line.match(/DOG/)
    puts('aaaaa')

    if type != nil 
      puts(type[0])
      break
    end        

  end
end
```

That are the first 3 lines of my file :

```
;?lalalalal60000065535-1362490443-0000006334-0000018467-0000000041en-lalalalallalalalalalalalaln Cell Generation
text/lalalalala1.0.0.1515
text/lalalala�DOG
```

When I run this code it shows me an error exactly when reading the third line of the file (where the word dog stands):

```
;?lalalalal60000065535-1362490443-0000006334-0000018467-0000000041en-lalalalallalalalalalalalaln Cell Generation
aaaaa

text/lalalalala1.0.0.1515
aaaaa

text/lalalala�DOG
/home/kik/Desktop/determine2.rb:16:in `match': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

BUT:
if I run just a a determine function with the following content:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
#encoding: utf-8

    def determine
    type="text/lalalala�DOG".match(/DOG/)
    puts(type)
end
```

it works perfectly.

What is going wrong there?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The third line in the file is:

```
text/lalalal»DOG
```

BUT when I print the thirf line of the file in ruby it shows up like:

```
text/lalalala�DOG
```

EDIT2:

> This format was also developed to support localization. Strings stored
>   within the file are stored as 2 byte UNICODE characters.The format of
>   the file is a binary file with data stored in network byte order
>   (big-endian format).

Comment: Are you sure that character is UTF-8? It shows up as unknown for me. What's the code?

Comment: @Linuxios if I run the code without #encoding :utf-8 I still recieve an error message with "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" and if I run the code type="text/lalalala�DOG".match(/DOG/) it works

Comment: What's the character code?

Comment: In your comment that character shows up as invalid for me. If you have invalid UTF-8 sequences, the string is damaged and some methods will generate exceptions like this.

Comment: How can I look the character code then?
@tadman Yeah, but why does it work when I type the string on my own and it doesnt work when the string is saved in a variable

Comment: I'm not sure where you got this character from, but it might not conform to the [UTF-8 spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). That character shows up as `"\U+FFEF\U+FFBF\U+FFBD"` when I copy and paste it into `irb`.

Comment: @tadman This character shows up as [239,191,189]. And I took a look into a file itself, the third line looks like:  lalala»DOG  BUT when I print the line in ruby is shows up to be lalala�DOG

Comment: You might have an encoding problem in your file. Are you sure it's UTF-8? Keep in mind the `encoding` header only affects source file encoding, and does not change the encoding of external files you open. You could try `File.open(filename, 'r:UTF8')` to force it.

Comment: @tadman m... no. I am not sure. How can I learn this? If I run a code without #encoding: utf-8 it tells me the following error: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError). Doesn't it mean, that the string in the file is in UTF-8?

Comment: @tadman no, it did not help, I still het the same error

Comment: If you can determine the encoding of the file, you can open it the correct way. It might be ISO-1252 or ISO-8859-1. If I put `»` in a file, in UTF-8 it encodes to bytes `[197, 187]`, not what you got. What you have is probably invalid.

Comment: can it help somehow ? "Strings stored within the file are stored as 2 byte UNICODE characters.The format of the file is a binary file with data stored in network byte order (big-endian format)."

Comment: @Katja  According to what you just said, you should use `UTF-16BE`.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe @Amadan is close, but has it backwards.  I'd do this:

```
File.open("/home/lala.txt", "r:ASCII-8BIT")
```

The character is not valid UTF-8, but for your purposes, it looks like 8-bit ASCII will work fine.  My understanding is that Ruby is using that encoding by default when you just use the string, which is why that works.

**Update:** Based on your most recent comment, it sounds like this is what you need:

```
File.open("/home/lala.txt", "rb:UTF-16BE")
```

Comment: It works, I mean I do not receive an error message BUT type = line.match(/DOG/) does not work. It does not find a word DOG in a file.

Comment: did not work :5:in `initialize': ASCII incompatible encoding needs binmode (ArgumentError)
 from /home/kik/Desktop/determine2.rb:5:in `open'

Comment: @Katja: I think that means you need a `b` in there; I just updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @DarshanComputing error again: `match': invalid byte sequence in UTF-16BE (ArgumentError)

Comment: Well, then your information is wrong; it's not big-endian UTF-16 after all.  Maybe it's a bug in the code generating the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
File.open("/home/lala.txt", "r:UTF-8")
```

There seems to be an issue with wrong encoding being used at some stage. `#encoding :utf` specifies only the encoding of the source file, which affects how the literal string is interpreted, and has no effect on the encoding that `File.open` uses.

Answer (score -1):

**Simple Solution for less number of files:**

@Katja open the file in some text editor and click on save as option and change its format to UTF-8 and click OK. pop up will be displayed to replace or create new. Replace existing file and you are on.